# Estrutura mysql em firebase/firestore

Tags: mysql, sql, firebase, nosql, firestore

Como criar uma coleção 1:1 e 1:n no firebase, como na imagens, onde tenho tabelas empresa, cidade e categorias, como ficaria a relação entre elas no firestore, principalmente a relação 1 empresas tem varias categorias.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

obs: tanto empresa quanto categoria tem vários elementos de dados, essa imagem é só um exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A estrutura de ambos (Realtime Database e Firestore) é mais ou menos a mesma, então vou responder de um mas que pode ser usado para o outro. Leia a documentaçao para mais detalhes

- [Documentação Firebase Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data)
- [Documentação Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)

Se você quer manter a mesma estrutura do SQL, basicamente você irá usar uma estrutura de nível raiz, por exemplo:

```
{
    empresa: {
        id_empresa_1: {
            nome: 'fulano',
            categoria: {
                id_categoria_1: true,
                id_categoria_2: true
            },
            cidade: 'id_cidade_1'
        }
    },
    categoria: {
        id_categoria_1: {
            nome: 'beltrano'
        }
    },
    cidade: {
        id_cidade_1: {
            nome: 'ciclano'
        }
    }
}
```

"Traduzindo" pro SQL, os objetos no nível raiz (emrpesa, cidade e categorias) são tabelas, cada objeto dentro deles é uma linha da respectiva tabela e as chaves desse objeto são as colunas

Mas você pode simplificar os objetos de empresa usando um objeto cidade dentro do objeto da empresa:

```
{
    empresa: {
        id_empresa_1: {
            nome: 'fulano',
            categoria: {
                id_categoria_1: true,
                id_categoria_2: true
            },
            cidade: {
                nome: 'ciclano'
            }
        }
    },
    //...
}
```

Porém isso causa um aninhamento dos dados e isso deve ser usado com cautela, apesar de simplificar a estrutura, pode dificultar (e até inviabilizar) consultas mais complexas